# Troubling In Laravel Roles and permission

Tags: laravel, permissions, middleware, roles

This is my admin middleware, in my Middleware I use Admin guard. First time I use Laravel Roles and permission on my project. But when I write code for roles and permission on my middleware, I can't access the admin panel.

What is the error? What can I do now? Is there any logical error in my middleware code?

```php
<?php
    
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Closure;
use Session;
use App\Admin;
use Auth;

class CheckRole {
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        if (Auth::guard('admin')->check() && Admin::where(['status' => '1'])) {

            $adminDetails = Admin::where('email', Session::get('remember_token'))->first();
            $adminDetails = json_decode(json_encode($adminDetails), true);
            if ($adminDetails['type'] === "admin") {
                $adminDetails['categories_access'] = 1;
                $adminDetails['products_access'] = 1;
                $adminDetails['orders_access'] = 1;
                $adminDetails['users_access'] = 1;
            }
            Session::put('adminDetails', $adminDetails);

            // Get Current Path
            $currentPath = Route::getFacadeRoot()->current()->uri();

            if ($currentPath === "admin/view-category" && Session::get('adminDetails')['categories_access'] == 0) {
                return redirect('/admin/dashboard')->with('flash_message_error', 'You have no access for this module');
            }

            if ($currentPath === "admin/view-product" && Session::get('adminDetails')['products_access'] == 0) {
                return redirect('/admin/dashboard')->with('flash_message_error', 'You have no access for this module');
            }

            if ($currentPath === "admin/add-product" && Session::get('adminDetails')['products_access'] == 0) {
                return redirect('/admin/dashboard')->with('flash_message_error', 'You have no access for this module');
            }

            return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect('admin/login');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe you are in a wrong track. you can use some famous roles permission packages like spatie permission checkout the docs from here : https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v3/introduction